# Difference between adverb and adverbial adjunct

Tags: adverbs, adjuncts

> He arrived **today**.
>
> He arrived.

Could we call adverb **today** as an **adverbial adjunct** because it still complete the meaning of sentence without it?

Comment: No: "today" is a pronoun. Adjuncts only occur in clause structure, so you don't need the word "adverbial". In your example, "today" is a noun phrase functioning as an adjunct of temporal location.

Comment: @BillJ according to ODE, the lexeme today is either a noun or adverb. In the example quoted above, it is an adverb in terms of lexical category.

Comment: @Lynnyo Yes, it does, but then we never use dictionaries for grammar! Items like "today", "yesterday", "tomorrow" etc. belong in the pronoun class. Thus "today" is best analysed as an adjunct of temporal location realised by an NP with a deictic pronoun as head.

Comment: @Lynnyo Here's why [it's not a great idea to rely on dictionaries for parts of speech! :-)](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635)

Answer (score 2):

**Today** functions as an [adverb of time](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-time/), telling when he arrived. Dictionaries usually present *[today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/today)* as an adverb. That's the most straightforward analysis.

If you wanted, you can call an adverb an *adverbial*, and describe it as an *adjunct* that provides additional information to the sentence. [Oxford Dictionaries explains the respective terms](https://web.archive.org/web/20201113091807/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/adverbials-and-adjuncts) in ways that allow this analysis. (Adverbs are also considered adverbials; as adjuncts they provide extra information,) The result is that it treats a very similar word (yesterday) in a similar sentence (She visited ... yesterday) as an adverbial adjunct:

> Adverbial adjuncts can provide extra information about: (...)
>
> when things happen: (...)
>
> - I can’t sleep **at night**.
> - She visited her family **yesterday**.

So yes, you *can* call **today**, like **yesterday** in the previous example, an adverbial adjunct.

There are also other explanations for what's going on here. Some guides like *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL) [analyze *today*, *yesterday*, and related words as pronouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/16755/327070) (link is to StackExchange answer on subject), and would describe this as a noun phrase used as an adjunct of temporal location. The result is similar to calling it an "adverbial adjunct," but CGEL goes to such lengths to better account for cases where *today* is clearly not functioning as an adverb.

Comment: +1 for the scholarship involved in showing that different authorities analyse the situation in different ways. It's interesting that you class CGEL as a 'guide'.

Answer (score -1):

The term *adverb* refers to a lexical category while the term *adverbial adjunct* denotes a syntactic role. The difference is that between categories and (syntactic) functions (which is elaborated in detail in ch.1 of the bulk volume *the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Note that CGEL is classed as a 'bulk volume' here. That's certainly descriptive in one sense, but ...